# Intuitive Understanding of this probability drawings question

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I'm doing this problem from Carol Ash's *The Probability Tutoring Book*

> Draw 20 times from the integers {1,2,3...,100}. Find the probability that your draws come out in increasing order if the drawings are with replacement

My attempt:
We are drawing with replacement, the probability of getting a greater number the 2nd, 3rd, 4th and 5th time depend on the previous draws, so I reasoned:

$$\sum_i\frac{1}{100^4}{\frac{100 - i}{100}}$$
But this doesn't work because $i$ - the variable we sum over - isn't measuring what our greatest number at any time is.

So I peeked at the answers:
$$\frac{100 \choose 20}{100^{20}}$$

The denominator, as I understand it, is the total number of possible drawings with replacement. The numerator is the total number of groups of 20 that I can make from the 100 numbers.

But these groupings don't have to necessarily be in increasing order. Also, I learned in high school that when we use the combination operator we draw without replacement... Can someone explain the numerator to me please(whether mathematically or intuitively)?

Answer (score 4):

In order for the draws to be in increasing order, the numbers drawn must all be distinct, so you must have drawn a set of $20$ different numbers. For each possible set of $20$ distinct integers there is exactly one string of draws in which the numbers are increasing, so there is exactly one successful (i.e., increasing) string of draws for each $20$-element subset of $\{1,2,\ldots,100\}$. There are $100^{20}$ possible strings of draws, so the probability of getting a successful one is $$\frac{\binom{100}{20}}{100^{20}}\;$$

The rule of thumb that we count combinations when the draw is without replacement and permutation when it is with replacement applies to straightforward problems, but it can’t be applied blindly in more involved settings. Here the point is that each draw in which the numbers are increasing is completely determined by the set of $20$ numbers drawn, because there’s exactly one increasing draw for each set of $20$ numbers. Thus, counting the sets of $20$ numbers actually amounts to counting the increasing draws of $20$ numbers: there’s a bijection between sets of $20$ numbers and increasing draws of $20$ numbers.

The real distinction is that combinations count **sets** of things of a certain size, while permutations count **sequences** of things.

Comment: In the last paragraph, maybe it would be clearer to say "each set of 20 *distinct* numbers" and "counting sets of 20 *distinct* numbers actually amounts to counting the increasing..." and "bijection between sets of 20 *distinct* numbers and ..."

Comment: @AlexOrtiz: If they’re increasing, they are necessarily distinct.

Comment: Right, I agree, but I was thinking of adding this for when you say "sets of 20 numbers" since that isn't specifying the numbers are increasing.

Comment: @AlexOrtiz: I honestly don’t see what you’re getting at. It doesn’t specify that the numbers are increasing because it’s an unordered set. That’s kind of the point: there is only one permutation of that set that **is** increasing, so counting the sets effectively **is** counting the increasing permutations.

Comment: Your last comment made me realize that I was thinking of "set" as "multiset," as in we draw 20 numbers and then those numbers exist in some collection, but there may be repeats.

Comment: @AlexOrtiz: Ah, okay. No, if I’d meant to include that possibility, I’d definitely have used the term *multiset*. And I’m pretty sure that this question is being asked at a level at which multisets are pretty unfamiliar.

Comment: This is a terrific insight that is explained extremely well. A well deserved +1 from me.